# Identifying physical network devices using /sys/class/net/<iface>

Tags: kernel, ip, ethernet, mac-address, veth

I wanted to know if there is a way to differentiate physical and virtual network devices. `ip a` doesn't have an option. So I am trying `/sys/class/net/<iface>`.
There are 2 attributes `addr_assign_type` and type, but type only tells `Ethernet` or `loopback` there is not way to tell if its virtual.

I wanted to know does `addr_assign_type` tell us the different?

As per my observation `/sys/class/net/<iface>/{eth|loopback}` gives `0` and `/sys/class/net/<iface>/{virtualdevice}` gives `1 or 3`.

Is there something I can infer from this?

Comment: Only physical devices seem to have a `device` link (`/sys/class/net/*/device`)

Answer (score 0):

Per [the sysfs-class-net page at at kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-net):

```
What:           /sys/class/net/<iface>/addr_assign_type
Date:           July 2010
KernelVersion:  3.2
Contact:        netdev@vger.kernel.org
Description:
            Indicates the address assignment type. Possible values are:

            == ============================
            0  permanent address
            1  randomly generated
            2  stolen from another device
            3  set (by) dev_set_mac_address
            == ============================
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run `ethtool -i <network interface>`, physical interfaces should have a `bus-info:` line that identifies an appropriate hardware device. For virtual devices, the `bus-info:` will be empty.

For `/sys`-based identification, you could do something like this:

```
if readlink /sys/class/net/$IFACE | grep -q /virtual/
then
    echo "$IFACE is virtual"
else
    echo "$IFACE is physical"
fi
```